# I am having parameter limitations with pyodbc. How do I manually perform inserts or escape the values to insert?

Tags: sql-server, escaping, pyodbc

Let's say I want to execute an insert in this connection, which is valid:

```
import pyodbc
CONNSTR = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
          "SERVER=....database.windows.net,1433;
          "UID=...;PWD=...;DATABASE=..."
connection = pyodbc.connect(CONNSTR, autocommit=True)
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Then, I make this insert, which is valid:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[products]([name], [regular_price], [sale_price], [type]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", ["Hello", 1.1, 1.1, "lalala"])
```

This is: I make the query using parameters, and then I insert one single record. This works (assume the table is valid and accepts sending those 4 columns).

But when I use 2100 or more arguments, I get an error:

```
>>> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[products]([name], [regular_price], [sale_price], [type]) VALUES " + ", ".join("(?, ?, ?, ?)" for _ in range(525)), ["Hello", 1.1, 1.1, "lalala"] * 525)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request. (8003) (SQLExecDirectW)')
>>> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[products]([name], [regular_price], [sale_price], [type]) VALUES " + ", ".join("(?, ?, ?, ?)" for _ in range(526)), ["Hello", 1.1, 1.1, "lalala"] * 526)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

So, it seems that using 2100 or more arguments is not allowed, and I need to support inserting up to 1000 records like this (in fact! this will be user-handled so I DON'T KNOW how many columns will the table have).

So my **question** is: How do I escape the arguments manually so I don't have to resort to using this argument-placeholder approach (which is limited on insert because of this)? Or, alternatively: Is there a driver-enabled method in the odbc adapters to insert a value through pyodbc (method which actually takes care of the escaping by itself)?

Comment: To insert multiple rows you should be using `.executemany()` instead of `.execute()`. Details in the wiki starting [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-params-with-fast_executemanyfalse-the-default)

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler alert: No. There is no built-in process. What I had to do comes like this:

1. Compute the number of columns per row to insert.
2. Compute the number of rows to insert "per batch" as `int(2099 / numcols)`.
3. Batch-insert using `"insert into mytable({col_list}) values ..."` using parameters `args_chunk`.

This will be explained now:

1. `col_list` will be `", ".join(cols)` while `numcols` will be `len(cols)`, being `cols` an array of strings with the columns to insert.
2. `args_chunk` will be a flattened version of `rows[index:index + batch_size]` considering `index` as iterated from `range(0, len(rows), batch_size)`.
3. `...` in the insert query will be `", ".join(["(?, ?...?, ?)"] * len(rows[index:index + batch_size]))` where the number of question marks is `numcols`.

So the logic goes like this:

1. Considering the number of columns (which will at most be 1024), insert an amount of rows that make the total number of arguments NOT pass 2099. Use this amount as a "safe" amount of rows to insert.
2. Each iteration will use that "safe" amount of rows.
3. The query, on each iteration, will have the appropriate number of rows (and arguments).
4. A last iteration may have a different (lower) number of rows.
5. By the end, all of them will be safely inserted.

Comment: Unless things have changed in recent versions of SQL Server, a "table value constructor" (TVC) can insert no more than 1000 rows regardless of the number of columns. You may want to test your approach with a list of columns where `len(cols) < 3`